# Write pixels image in a CSV file

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, image-processing, byte

I'm learning image processing and I'm stuck. I wanna read an image and write the bytes in a CSV file, separated by `;`. I convert the image to a byte array then write it. But it seems the array does not contain all the image information causing an error in `file.WriteLine()`.

Here's the code in `C#`:

```
// Creación del objeto imagen
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:/Users/Sean Sabe/Documents/ImageProcessing/Images/cato.jpg");

// Mostrar datos de la imagen
Console.WriteLine("Image Size: " + image.PhysicalDimension + " Depth: " + image.PixelFormat);

// Convertir la imagen en array de bytes
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));

// Escribir la matriz con los bytes
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"D:/Users/Sean Sabe/Documents/ImageProcessing/cato.csv"))
{
    for(int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            file.WriteLine(String.Join(";", bytes[x + (y * image.Width)]));
        }
        file.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

What is written in cato.csv is the following:

```
255
216
255
224
0
16
74
.
.
.
```

and so on until the row `37132` in column A.

Comment: Additionally, you seem to assume that one byte equals one pixel. That will come and bite you in the behind after you fixed your file.WriteLine/String.Join problem...

Comment: `String.Join()` is for creating a string with any number of values but you're only writing one at a time. I can only guess what you are trying to do there. Why don't you show what it's writing to the file and explain what information appears to be missing?

Comment: As far as I know, an image converted to byte array does not equal the pixel contents of the image... you need to use `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy` for that. And depending on the format you'll end up with up to four bytes per pixel, and padding. Just that array of bytes would not be enough to reconstruct the image. There's a _reason_ images have headers.

Comment: @JonathanWood I edited the question. What I want to write in the `CSV` file is the full code of colors whatever the image is, RGB or grayscale.

Comment: @Nyerguds If I want to manipulate the image information for other processing I need color data not bytes of the image?

Comment: So how do you want to _represent_ that color data in your CSV file? My suggestion would be a simple (AA)RRGGBB hexadecimal colour code. It's pretty universal, and as compact as you can get in text.

Comment: @Nyerguds I think the approach of @rs232 is what I need. But I am wondering how to write the full RGB pixels if `Color color` just splits in `color.R` , `color.G` and `color.B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slow, but simple and effective way is to use Bitmap instead of Image (since you use .jpg bitmap anyway):

```
Bitmap image = Image.FromFile(@"D:/Users/Sean Sabe/Documents/ImageProcessing/Images/cato.jpg") as Bitmap;
```

Now you can obtain a color of every pixel of your image with

```
Color c = image.GetPixel(x, y);
```

After that, you can write your color's R, G, and B values to your CSV file.

Comment: So bytes does not contain color information, correct?

Comment: I think this is what I needed. But what happens if it's a grayscale image?

Comment: Bytes do contain the color information. The information might, however, be organized in a different way, depending on the image format and other options, if you still want to use them you need to parse an image header and go through all the ins and outs of the data representation. It is technically possible, but pretty complicated.

Comment: Gray is a color. This means that when you ask for a pixel color, it will return you a color which represents a corresponding shade of gray.

Comment: I managed to solve what I needed thanks to your answer. I have it clear now. Starting from a bitmap I wrote the pixels in a CSV separately for RGB. Now I can read each .csv and display the full image using `Color.FromArgb` .